# Display bug with votes and edited answers

Tags: bug, edits, voting, live-refresh

Today, I ran into a nice little glitch, probably in JavaScript redraw code:

1. Downvote an answer, and leave the tab open.
2. Open a new tab and either edit the answer or have the original OP do so.
3. Remove the downvote and change to an upvote from the new tab.
4. Check the original tab and use the link to refresh the answer because it has been edited...
5. Observe that the arrows for both down and up votes are marked as selected (blue in this particular case).

> [image: Screenshot, up and down at the same time]

Comment: This seems like a very bizarre edge case. How often is this going to happen when you're not intentionally trying to break the system?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I've seen it twice in the wild. I use SE with a lot of tabs open, leaving things I plan to comment on open. It's quite common for somebody to edit a post in response to a first round of comments or votes and for me to reverse a vote. It's an edge case, but not a totally crazy one.

Comment: I often end up with multiple tabs open for the same post, usually unknowingly. I've never run across this before though.

Answer (score -2):

Then don't do that.

Seriously. When is this a problem for anyone? What would be the maximum harm if it did?

Comment: It's not a big deal, its just a bug report on an edge case. Sometimes programming bugs are better squashed earlier so they are known to do exactly and completely what they are advertised to do or they create more bugs that are harder to find down the road. They could choose not to fix this, but at least maybe the programmer in charge of that big will have a chance to review the code and see if its doing its job.