# Post shows both upvoted and downvoted after live-refresh following vote change in separate tab

Tags: bug, live-refresh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display bug with votes and edited answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147506/display-bug-with-votes-and-edited-answers)

I noticed this weirdness when refreshing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945029/split-string-combinations#12945063) after an edit.

[image: up, down or both?]

I'm not 100% sure, but this is how I think it happened:

1. I had this question open in a tab and I downvoted the answer (it was incorrect at the time).
2. While in a different tab, I went back and noticed the user had edited his answer so I changed my down vote to an up vote.
3. Back in the original tab I clicked the "this post has been edited" link to reload it, and suddenly both the up and down vote arrows were highlighted.

Of course, this is just an issue with the live refresh, so after reloading the page it correctly only highlights the up vote arrow.

I'm running Chrome 22 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: [Reproduced](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ol2B.png) on Chrome 22/Win7

Comment: Didn't happen for me on FF17/OSX10.7.5; perhaps a chrome bug?

Comment: @Kevin: I assume that was you up and downvoting me just now? You didn't edit though, so how did you trigger the live refresh?

Comment: Just tried with an edit and I'm not even getting the live refresh. (And yes, I usually do)

Comment: @Kevin It looks like you won't get a live refresh if you performed the edit yourself.